# Ivy retrieve latest artifact with pre release

Tags: ant, ivy

I have an ant task that uses ivy:retrive task with revision set to something like "1.2.3+". My problem is that I have artifacts which have the same first three digits but end differently.

Artifacts sample:

- 1.2.2-b1-hash
- 1.2.3-b2-someHash
- 1.2.3-b3-anotherHash
- 1.2.3-b4-someOtherHash
- 1.2.4-b5-latestVersion

Currently I have the following target:

```xml
<target name="retrieve-apps">
        <ivy:retrieve 
            inline="true" 
            conf="core" 
            organisation="com.myOrg.myApp" 
            module="myApp" 
            revision="1.2.3+" 
            pattern="${basedir}/[artifact].[ext]" />
</target>
```

When I run the target, I always get the artifact "1.2.3-b2-someHash". Is there a way that I can change the revision or pattern to get the artifact "1.2.3-b4-someOtherHash" while preserving a rule for the first three digit ?

I have tried to use the `latest.integration` as revision but it returns "1.2.4-b5-lastestVersion" which is not what I want. I have also tried to use "1.2.3-b3-someOtherHash" but I will have to change it every time I want to upgrade to the latest build of that version.